# The normed space of functions such that $x \mapsto \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is integrable

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

I was looking over some functional analysis problem sheets from Oxford and question 6 on [this](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/mod/assign/view.php?id=638) one caught my attention. I will copy it below:

> Let $I=[0,2]$ and consider $$X=\{f\in L^1(I):\int_I\frac{1}{x}|f(x)|dx<\infty\} \text{ equipped with }||f||_X:=\int_I\frac{1}{x}|f(x)|dx$$ as well as $Y=C(I)\cap X$.
> *You may use without proof that* $(X, ||\cdot||_X)$ *is a normed space as well as that* $(L^1(I), ||\cdot||_{L^1})$ *and* $(C(I), ||\cdot||_{sup})$ *are Banach spaces.*
> (a) Prove that $(X, ||\cdot||_X)$ is complete but that $(Y, ||\cdot||_X)$ is not complete.
> (b) Determine a norm $||\cdot||_Y$ on $Y$ so that $(Y, ||\cdot||_Y)$ is complete. Carefully justify your answer.

I wasn't really able to actually show that $(X, ||\cdot||_X)$ is complete, but apart from that I think that my solutions are correct. Here they are:
a) Let $(f_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X, ||\cdot||_X)$ and $g(x)\equiv x$. We have $$\int_I |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|dx=\int_I \frac{1}{x}\cdot|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\cdot x\le 2||f_n-f_m||_X.$$ This inequality shows us that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $||\cdot||_{L^1}$. Since $L^1(I)$ is a Banach space, we know that there is some $f\in L^1(I)$ such that $||f_n-f||_{L^1}\to 0$. It is now easy to see that $g\cdot f\in X$ and I think that this function should be the limit of $(f_n)$, but I wasn't really able to show this. I feel that, however, this should be the way to go and I would like some help to finish this line of thought.

To show that $(Y, ||\cdot||_X)$ is not complete, consider the sequence $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
x^n, & 0\le x\le 1 \\
1, & 1<x\le 2
\end{cases}$ in $Y$. Let $f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & 0\le x\le 1 \\
1, & 1<x\le 2
\end{cases}$. It is easy to see that $||f_n-f||_X\to 0$, but $f\notin C(I)$. It is also easy to see that $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, so we get that $(Y, ||\cdot||_X)$ is not complete.

b)I think that we can define $||f||_Y=||f||_{sup}+||f||_X$ for $f\in Y$ and this will do the trick. Consider $(f_n)$ a Cauchy sequence in $(Y, ||\cdot||_Y)$. Then $$||f_n-f||_{sup}\le ||f_n-f||_Y\to 0 \text{ as } m, n \to \infty,$$ so $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(C(I), ||\cdot||_{sup})$, which is a Banach space, so $(f_n)$ is convergent in this space. Thus, there is some $f\in C(I)$ such that $||f_n-f||_{sup}\to 0$. Since $I$ has finite measure, we can use this uniform convergence to change the limit and the integral to conclude that $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_I \frac{1}{x}|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx=0$, which then helps us to show that $f\in X$ too (i.e. $f\in Y$), so that we may now rewrite the first limit as $||f_n-f||_Y \to 0$ and we are done, we showed that $(Y, ||\cdot||_Y)$ is complete.

Comment: Let $h(x) = 1/x$ and $g(x) = x.$ By definition, $(f_n)$ is fundamental in $X$ means that $(h f_n)$ is fundamental in $L^1,$ so $h f_n \to h f$ in $L^1$ and $f = g(hf) \in L^1$ since $g \in L^\infty.$ So you are done: $\|f_n - f\|_X = \|hf_n - hf\|_1 \to 0.$

Comment: Your proof of the last part is incorrect. If $f_n$ tends uniformly to $f$ and $f_n\in X,$ it does not imply that $f\in X.$

Comment: @WilliamM. thanks, I tried something along those lines, but I always got confused in the multiplications.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc What I meant was that we could use the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_I \frac{1}{x}|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx=0$ to conclude that $f\in X$ (which follows from the uniform convergence or by Fatou's Lemma like you did in your answer). I think that's basically what you did too for that part.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I'm not sure how your comment is relevant. I was just mentioning the proof of $X$ being complete. There is no uniform converge, only $L^1$ and in $X.$ In fact, my comment is your first two lines of your solution.

Comment: @WilliamM. I think he was referring to my proof of the last part of the question.

Comment: @WilliamM. Indeed I was commenting the proof in OP.

Comment: Let $f_n=x^{1/n}(-\log x+1)^{-1}$ for $x>0$ and $f_n(0)=0.$ Then $f_n\in X\cap C[0,2]$ and $f_n $ tends uniformly to $f(x)=(-\log x+1)^{-1}$ but $f\notin X.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc interesting. Here is my reasoning. I thought that I could write $\int_I \frac{1}{x}|f(x)|dx\le ||f-f_n||_X+\int_I \frac{1}{x}|f_n(x)|dx$ and I know that $||f_n-f||_X\to 0$ by using the uniform convergence. Then I thought that I can just take $\limsup$ in this inequality and the boundness of $||f_n||_X$ (which follows from the fact that it is a Cauchy sequence) then shows that $\int_I \frac{1}{x}|f(x)|dx<\infty$. Isn't this right?

Comment: The quantity $\|f_n-f\|_X$ does not make sense if you do not know that $f\in X.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc ok, that's an abuse of notation, so I will make that rigorous. I can definitely write that $\int_I \frac{1}{x}|f(x)|dx\le \int_I \frac{1}{x}|f-f_n(x)| dx+\int_I \frac{1}{x}|f_n(x)|dx$. This definitely makes sense because all the integrals exist and now I can take $\limsup$: the first integral goes to $0$ using the uniform convergence argument I mentioned and the second one is bounded since the sequence is Cauchy. Isn't this right?

Comment: No. The second integral does not tend to $0$  It can be infinite

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc how can it be infinite? Our sequence $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $||\cdot ||_X$, so it is bounded, i.e. there is some $M>0$ such that $||f_n||_X\le M$ for all $n$ and the second integral is precisely $||f_n||_X$.

Comment: The second one, i.e. the first one after $\le$ sign. You have to prove it is finite, that's the main point.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc ok, now I understand your concern. But as I was saying, isn't the uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ to $f$ and the fact that our interval is bounded enough to conclude that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_I \frac{1}{x}|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx=0$ by simply interchanging the limit and the integral? And I think that this solves the problem.

Comment: No. The integral can be infinite for every $n.$  So the limit is also infinite. See my example. The boundedness of the interval is not sufficient due to the factor $1/x$  which is unbounded close to $0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thanks a lot. I figured out too that the $1/x$ factor messes up the trick I had in mind and I was just coming to comment this now. Thank you for your patience and for your solution, you really helped me to understand better this type of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Uf=xf.$ Then $U$ is the isometry from $L^1$ into $X.$ Moreover $U$ is surjective. Indeed if $g\in X$ then $f:=x^{-1}g\in L^1 $ and $Uf=g.$ As $L^1$ is complete so is $X$ as it is isometric with $L^1.$

Concerning (c), the norm $\|f\|=\|f\|_\infty +\|f\|_X$ proposed in OP is fine. The proof could be as follows. If $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, then it is uniformly convergent to a continuous function $f$ and $\|f_n-f\|_\infty \to 0.$ We have to show that $f\in X$ and $\|f_n-f\|_X\to 0.$ By the Fatou lemma we get
$$\int\limits_0^2{1\over x}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\,dx \le \liminf_m\int\limits_0^2{1\over x}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\,dx
=\liminf_m\|f_n-f_m\|_X$$ For fixed $\varepsilon >0$ choose $N$ so that  $\|f_n-f_m\|<\varepsilon $ for $n,m\ge N.$ Then for $n\ge N$ we get
$$\int\limits_0^2{1\over x}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\,dx\le \varepsilon$$ In particular $f_n-f\in X$ and $\|f_n-f\|_X\le \varepsilon$ for $n\ge N.$ Hence $f\in X.$ The above shows that $\|f_n-f\|_X\to 0.$